# Find repetition with regex

Tags: regex

I would like to catch with regex any repetition of these three characters `. / -`

For example I would like to find:

```
"a//fsdf"
"a/-fd"
"v.-"
```

But not this one:

```
"a/f.d-qwe"
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: What is exact output you need? Just `//`, `/-`...? Or validate the whole string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this one? :

```
[\.\/\-]{2,}
```

**[Here](https://regex101.com/r/bH9wN9/1)** are the test results

Comment: `(\/|\.|\-){2,}` is too inefficient, I'd remove it from the answer.

Comment: Anyway, too much escaping. You only might need to escape the forward slash. Other characters are treated as literals. Have a look at [BACKSLASH HELL](https://tudorbarbu.ninja/backslash-hell/). Escape only when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use curly braces, to specify the amount of repetition:

```
[./-]{2,}
```

This will match the string of characters with length exceeding 2.

Comment: You need to escape `-` inside square brackets, otherwise it makes a range of characters.

Comment: @Barmar Not if it is the first or last character!

Comment: That might work in javascript or python, but not in php

Comment: @stribizhev Hmm strange, in my experience it never worked in php unless I escaped the characters. You win this round ;)

Comment: This is exactly how I would answer the question, but it is too unclear for me right now.

Comment: @Patrick2607 You can always choose different delimiters for a pattern in PHP. In the ideone link above; it is `~`.